# problem in adding data in MongoDB through node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

problem while adding data in mongodb. I have nodejs code and mongodb. code successfully connects with mongodb but when I want to post data error appears.

```
Listening on port 3000.....
```

connected to mongoDB
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse ()
    at parse (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Users\hp\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

Comment: You seem to try de parse a Json (or a javascript object) using Json.parse(myString) of something wich is already an object, and not a string, representing an object. If you parse your response, you should post your payload object as a string ( ex: '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}').
You should also validate your Json using a tool like this to make sure your json data are valid: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Can you please provide the code of yours where you are trying to insert the data

Comment: ok i will provide you code. give me your email or any contact?